# Core data background task causing data to disappear

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an odd issue with core data. I have an app with nested tables - one table views a list of lessons, clicking on a lessons segues to a new table that shows the students that attended.

Works fine - displays data perfectly even after I add a new lesson and students that attended. Problem happens after a random amount of time (seconds rather than minutes) after I have created and saved this data. The lesson will still show in the first table but the students who attended blanks out.

The data is still there as if I stop then start simulator - data is right there.

Have ruled out not passing the context correctly between the views. The issue seems to occur after some background sql code runs - shown below:

```
2012-03-09 17:08:16.772 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2012-03-09 17:08:16.774 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2012-03-09 17:08:16.775 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZSTUDENT SET Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2012-03-09 17:08:16.776 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZSTUDENT SET Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2012-03-09 17:08:16.777 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLESSON(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZDATE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
2012-03-09 17:08:16.786 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Z_2STUDENTSATTENDED(Z_2LESSONSATTENDED, Z_4STUDENTSATTENDED) VALUES (11, 2)
2012-03-09 17:08:16.787 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Z_2STUDENTSATTENDED(Z_2LESSONSATTENDED, Z_4STUDENTSATTENDED) VALUES (11, 1)
2012-03-09 17:08:16.788 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2012-03-09 17:08:16.791 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
2012-03-09 17:08:16.792 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0014s
2012-03-09 17:08:16.793 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
2012-03-09 17:08:16.795 Club Manager[5147:12f1b] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0019s
```

This seems to make my fetch for the 2nd table act differently - have played with different settings to make sure fetch doesn't cache objects but doesn't seem to solve....

```
- (void) setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Student"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY lessonsAttended = [cd] %@", self.lesson];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
   [request setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:YES];
    [ request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

   self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.lesson.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                               cacheName:nil];

}
```

Anyone know what the background job might be and why it changes how my fetch works would be very gratefully received as this has been driving me mad for days.

First time asking a question here so be gentle with me ;)

John

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this - there seemed to be a problem with the predicate I was using - by changing:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY lessonsAttended = [cd] %@", self.lesson];
```

To:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY lessonsAttended.date = [cd] %@", self.lesson.date];
```

It started to work - I now consistently get the right data rather than it changing after what I guess was an autosave of the context/managed document.

Would still know why this is different if anyone can answer.

REgards,

John.